# Fatal error: Class 'http\Client' not found in

Tags: php

I am trying to call Rest API using HttpClient but getting 
**error "Fatal error: Class 'http\Client' not found in"**

**PHP Code :**

```
$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;

$body = new http\Message\Body;
$body->addForm(NULL, array(
      array(
                'name' => 'attachment',
                'type' => null,
                'file' => REPORTPATH . $_SERVER['HTTP_DISTRIBUTORAPIKEY'] . "\\08122017123602.zip",
                'data' => null
            )
        ));

 $request->setRequestUrl('http://192.168.1.55/api/upload');
 $request->setRequestMethod('POST');
 $request->setBody($body);

 $request->setHeaders(array(
            'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
            'foldername' => '1HUBH',
            'distributorcode' => '1HUBH'
        ));

 $client->enqueue($request)->send();
 $response = $client->getResponse();

 echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Do you have an autoloader ? Is it required?

Comment: No I dont have any autoloader

Comment: Maybe you should look at `spl_autoload_register` or [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: you should include `http\Client;` file.

Comment: @ urfusion How to include http\Client;??

Comment: `include 'path_of_client_file';` at top of the file

Comment: @urfusion: Warning: include(D:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Client): failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Comment: path should be relative and according to project. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @urfusion : i know what include function does, but where to find http\Client? i have included like include 'http\Client';

Comment: You should use any of library of `http` for that.
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: if including gives: `include(D:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Client): failed to open stream: Permission denied`, then you probably need the appropriate permissions for the file.

Comment: That code was generated by [Insomnia REST client](https://support.insomnia.rest/article/37-code-snippet-generation), and they don't provide what library is, much less its link.